# Call javascript function through url on otherpage while Redirecting

Tags: javascript, php

I need to call a javascript function in `index.php` when I redirect to `index.php` from another page with some URL queries.

Here is my actual url: `index.php?id=10&func=view`. I need to wake up a javascript function which is in `index.php` with this URL.

Comment: Did you try something already? Would be helpful to see what you tried and how your code looks like.

Comment: put the javascript inside the if condition like this if($_GET['func']=='view'){ <script> function view(){  ....    } view() </script>}

Comment: Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: this one...`index.php?id=10&func=view&javascript:agentFee();`

Comment: @JYoThI Now i did like this..but i asked if any is there means that would be better

Comment: You should also _always_ post your code and _be clear_ in your question what you actually are asking.

Comment: i think it's not possible call javascript via url query parameter as you given in comment  @Jana

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic this question belongs on the site [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/), and not SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a session variable in your php code

`$_SESSION["jsload"] = "1";`

And then check if the variable is set in the index.php

```
<?php 
        if ( isset($_SESSION['jsload'])=="1" ) { ?>
        //javascript here
        <?php 
        }
?>
```

Make sure you use `session_start()` function on both pages

And unset and destroy the session once used

Answer (score 0):

[Look into `$_GET` parameters.](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)

Then try something like this:

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
 //Whatever code you want to return javascript with i.e. "echo $myJavascriptCode"
}
```

You could also include a main javascript file in your index page, and have a function that checks if a certain URL parameter exists. Here's one that works (albeit hacky):

```
if (window.location.search.indexOf('id=') > -1) {
    myFunction();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use callback js  function to call your function when page is loading like the below:

> URL: index.php?onload=myCallBack&id=10

And below is javascript code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  var myCallBack = function() {
    /your code is here
  });
  </script>
```

Hope this help!!!